# Calculate time taken to load a window once all async service call is done

Tags: objective-c, performance, macos, asynchronous

How to calculate the time taken to load a view/window? This can be done by this:

```
NSDate *startTime=[NSDate date];

//some code to load another window from winController

NSDate *endTime=[NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval diff = [endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
NSLog(@"Time to load is %f seconds.\n\n\n",diff);
```

---

But it will not calculate the total and exact time taken. To load a window, and then in init and awakeFromNib it asynchronously calls services, loads custom views, populates tableviews etc, and which is spread on dozens of classes/controllers and scores of methods.

If I use the above(program shown), the `endTime` is reached while spinner continues to spin and service calls are in progress.

I can check by watching Clock that it takes more than a minute to load the window, and to ready to perform any action on it, but `diff` is calculates to  0.5 seconds something.

Now the problem is that I can not change the whole code of project, however I can insert few things in between.

How to do this, suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to get an exact time until the progress indicator is vanished or do you want to understand what makes it to load for a long time ?

Comment: I need the actual difference from button click to Window getting ready. As even after progressIndicator stop window doesn't accepts any event.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Define "getting ready". Also, why don't you just grab the date before alloc-initting the window, then you again obtain the current date when it has finished loading, then you just get the difference.

Comment: @H2CO3: window is loaded but there are so many async service calls happing behind the scene. and even `windowDidFinishLoading` gets executed before the async call is done.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I mean, for the async call, you do have a completion handler, don't you? Put your timer code there.

Comment: @H2CO3: It may be, Or It must be somewhere. But finding for each buttonClick and codes are scattered in dozens of classes. It will be tough work to check. Can't I do something from the IBACtion itself, that once every thing gets complete a callback comes or the process dont reach NSDate *endTime=[NSDate date];

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No, not quite... Maybe runtime hacking? Hooking UIControl?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late and not sure if you are still searching for an answer or no(but it might other people searching for solution to similar problems).But in such cases you have to keep track of your code i.e. you need to know which callback from your async calls get called in the last. It is easy enough to trace. What I usually do is very common and simple, place NSLog(%@"1")... NSLog(%@"any_number") in those callbacks. And check which gets printed last. That way you can just place your endtimer code in that callback and know how much time it takes to load your window. Hope this helps someone.